# Sprite image is only longitudinally arranged

Tags: sass, sprite, compass

It seems to waste too much space. I want it more like this: http://style.aliunicorn.com/wimg/site/group-en/ru/buyer/sprite/header-sprite.png?t=15eb4a27_0

My .scss:

```
$icon-sprite-dimensions: true;
@import "compass/utilities/sprites";
@import "index/icon/*.png";
@include all-icon-sprites;
```

How can I set the .scss profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "smart" layout configuration option.

```
$mysprite-layout: smart;
```

http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/sprite-layouts/